# Intento mostrar varios divs ocultos

Tags: div, onclick

Tengo varios enlaces (y se van agregando mas con el tiempo), cada uno me debe mostrar un div diferente con su respectivo contenido y la opcion de cerrarlo.
Para un solo div me funciona, necesito de su ayuda para lograr poder abrir mas de uno, sin tener en cuenta la cantidad, ya que se va a ir agregando nuevo contenido, y nunca se muestran 2 divs a la vez.

Este es el codigo del enlace que muestra el div oculto

```html
<a href="#" onclick="mostrarVersiculo();">2 Pedro 3, 8</a>
```

y el codigo javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function mostrarVersiculo() {
  var x = document.getElementById("versiculo");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

Luego tengo el div con el contenido a mostrar y su enlace para cerrar

```html
<div id="versiculo" style="display:none">
CONTENIDO DEL DIV
<a href="#" onclick="cerrarversiculo('versiculo');">Cerrar DIV</a>
</div>
```

Y el javascript para cerrar el div

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function cerrarversiculo(versiculo) {
    var e = document.getElementById('versiculo');
          e.style.display = 'none';
   }
</script>
```

Lo que necesito es hacer eso pero que me funcione con varios enlaces a medida que los vaya agregando.
Como ven, tengo poco conocimiento, y uso javascript.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Todos los divs tienen la misma `id`? Cada `id` debe ser única. Si querés que varios elementos compartan un mismo identificador tendrías que usar `class='versiculo'`. Te muestro un ejemplo de cómo podrías solucionarlo. Otra manera sería haciendo que cada `div` tenga una id única y que se envíe esa id al llamar la función.

```
<div>
  <a href="#" onclick="mostrarVersiculo(event);">2 Pedro 3, 8</a>
  <div class="versiculo" style="display: none;">
    CONTENIDO DEL DIV1
    <!-- se envía la variable global `event` para saber qué elemento disparó el evento -->
    <a href="#" onclick="cerrarversiculo(event);">Cerrar DIV</a>
  </div>

  <a href="#" onclick="mostrarVersiculo(event);">2 Pedro 3, 9</a>
  <div class="versiculo" style="display: none;">
    CONTENIDO DEL DIV2
    <a href="#" onclick="cerrarversiculo(event);">Cerrar DIV</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function mostrarVersiculo(e) {
    // elem == elemento clickeado
    var elem = e.target;
    // vers == elemento que se encuentra después de elem
    var vers = elem.nextElementSibling;
    // (no debería haber ningún elemento entre el que llama a mostrarVersiculo
    // y el que contiene al que llama a cerrarversiculo para que funcione)
    if (vers.style.display === "block") {
      vers.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      vers.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  function cerrarversiculo(e) {
    var elem = e.target;
    // parent == elemento que contiene al elemento que llamó a la función
    var parent = elem.parentElement;
    parent.style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Perfecto. Me funciono tal cual yo queria. Muchas gracias